# Sum rows in a table if one column's value is also in another table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables like the following. For each product and day, I'd like to sum the amount in table_1 if both the sender and receiver were top clients in table_2 for the same product and day.

Table_1:

| product | date | sender | receiver | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 2001-01-01 | A | B | 5 |
| X | 2001-01-01 | A | C | 2 |
| X | 2001-01-01 | B | D | 1 |
| X | 2001-01-02 | B | C | 10 |
| X | 2001-01-02 | A | D | 3 |
| Y | 2001-01-01 | A | E | 5 |

Table_2:

| product | date | top client |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 2001-01-01 | A |
| X | 2001-01-01 | B |
| X | 2001-01-01 | D |
| X | 2001-01-02 | B |
| X | 2001-01-02 | C |
| Y | 2001-01-01 | C |

And the final output would have one row per product-day. For product X on date 2001-01-01, receiver C is not a top client in table_2, so the total_amount for X on 2001-01-01 is the sum of 5 and 1 only, not 2. For product X on 2001-01-02, only B and C were top clients, so the total_amount is only 10, not 10+3.

| product | date | total_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 2001-01-01 | 6 |
| X | 2001-01-02 | 10 |
| Y | 2001-01-01 | 0 |

I tried the following code:

```
select product, date, sum(amount) as total_amount from table_1 
  where (sender in (select top_client from table_2))
  and (receiver in (select top_client from table_2))
  group by product, date
```

However, this code looks at all the top_clients from table_2, not only the top_clients for a specific product-date. For example, receiver C was considered a top client for product X on date 2001-01-01, total_amount for that product-day ended up being 8 when it should be 6. The table I got was the following, and it's not what I want,

| product | date | total_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 2001-01-01 | 8 |
| X | 2001-01-02 | 13 |
| Y | 2001-01-01 | 0 |

I also tried to group the top_clients in table_2:

```
select product, date, sum(amount) as total_amount from table_1
where sender in unnest((select array_agg(top_client) from table_2 
group by product, date )) and receiver in unnest((select array_agg(top_client) from table_2 group by product, date ))
group by product, date
```

However, I got the following error:
"Scalar subquery produced more than one element"

What is the right way of creating an array of top_clients for a product-date? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join table 2 to table 1 twice.

In the next step the `amount` is set to zero, if no sender or no receiver were joined.

This is a good solution for small datasets:

```sql
with tbl as (Select "X" product,    "01.01.2001" date,  "A" sender, "B" receiver,   5 amount
Union ALL Select    "X",    "01.01.2001",   "A",    "C",2
Union ALL Select    "X",    "01.01.2001",   "B",    "D",1
Union ALL Select    "X",    "02.01.2001",   "B",    "C",10,
Union ALL Select    "X",    "02.01.2001",   "A",    "D",3,
Union ALL Select    "Y",    "01.01.2001",   "A",    "E",5,
),
table_2 as (Select  "X" product,    "01.01.2001" date , "A" top_client,
Union ALL Select    "X",    "01.01.2001",   "B",
Union ALL Select    "X",    "01.01.2001",   "D",
Union ALL Select    "X",    "02.01.2001",   "B",
Union ALL Select    "X",    "02.01.2001",   "C",
Union ALL Select    "Y",    "01.01.2001",   "C",
)

select 
tbl.product,    tbl.date,
sum(if(A.top_client is not null and B.top_client is not null, amount,0))    total_amount
#tbl.*,
#A.top_client as sender_ok,
#B.top_client as receiver_ok,
from tbl
left join table_2 A
on tbl.product=A.product and tbl.date=A.date and tbl.sender=A.top_client

left join table_2 B
on tbl.product=B.product and tbl.date=B.date and tbl.receiver=B.top_client

#where A.top_client is not null and B.top_client is not null 
group by 1,2
```

For large datasets, first merge both tables by `union` them instead of a join condition. The `flaggy` column is to distinguish these two. Please mark the columns, which are only present in one table by `null` in the other one.  Then use two windows function (`over`) for the search of the sender/ receiver. The `max(flaggy)` will be one if the sender is present in table 2.

```sql
with tbl as (Select "X" product,    "01.01.2001" date,  "A" sender, "B" receiver,   5 amount
Union ALL Select    "X",    "01.01.2001",   "A",    "C",2
Union ALL Select    "X",    "01.01.2001",   "B",    "D",1
Union ALL Select    "X",    "02.01.2001",   "B",    "C",10,
Union ALL Select    "X",    "02.01.2001",   "A",    "D",3,
Union ALL Select    "Y",    "01.01.2001",   "A",    "E",5,
),
table_2 as (Select  "X" product,    "01.01.2001" date , "A" top_client,
Union ALL Select    "X",    "01.01.2001",   "B",
Union ALL Select    "X",    "01.01.2001",   "D",
Union ALL Select    "X",    "02.01.2001",   "B",
Union ALL Select    "X",    "02.01.2001",   "C",
Union ALL Select    "Y",    "01.01.2001",   "C",
),
tbl_merge as (
Select 0 as flaggy, # to distinguish the tables
 product, date, sender, receiver, 
 amount 
from tbl
union all
select 1, # flaggy set to one 
 product, date, top_client,top_client, 
 null # beacuse amount column missing
from table_2

)

select 
product,date,
sum(if(flaggy_test=2, amount,0)) as total_amount 
from (
select *,
max(flaggy) over (partition by product,date,sender)+
max(flaggy) over (partition by product,date,receiver) as flaggy_test
from tbl_merge
)
where flaggy=0
group by 1,2
order by 1 desc
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, my actual tables both have over 40 million rows, and when I tried to join, I got the error that the job exceeded BigQuery's capacity. Is there another to do this without needing to request more computational power from BigQuery?

Comment: @fatpandabot I hoped your data would be small enough for the easy solution with joining. The other solution is a bit complicated, but should perform much better and faster. Please give it a try and tell if this worked out.